Issue while composer update in Magento 2 cloud
We want to install a new module in our project. For this, I have used Composer to install it and below are the steps followed:

The current version of Magento is the 2.4.6 cloud edition.
When I have installed the Adyen module using the command: composer require adyen/module-payment --no-update
Then I executed: the composer update
After this, when I checked Magento version is updated to 2.4.6-p7

Moving from 2.4.6 to 2.4.6-p7 is a big change, and we don't have time to upgrade to the latest version so we want to maintain our old version.
Can anyone help us to understand how we can achieve this?

No Need to Update Composer When Installing Module Using Composer
If installing the "adyen/module-payment" module via Composer, you don't need to update the entire Composer package repository. Instead, follow these installation steps:

Require the Adyen Payment module:
composer require adyen/module-payment


Install the module:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade


Deploy static content (if you're in production mode):
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy


Clear cache:
php bin/magento cache:clean



With these steps, the "adyen/module-payment" module will be installed without running a full composer update.
Set up the plugin in Adobe Commerce

Thanks Ronak. This helped me to solve the problem. I was confused about using composer update but then I went to the adobe commerce document and got clarity that we should not use the update command.

Basically when we upgrade the magento version that time only we use "composer update" command.

Correct. Somehow I got confused and executed this update command. And I got involved in solving this upgrade issue rather than focusing on what I had done.

Accept the answer if you're satisfied, as it may be helpful for others. Thank you, and happy coding!
